# replace words in pandas one dataframe with words in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below two dataframes

```
(Pdb) df
                msg
0               the
1               wi
2               fi
3              **a/c**

(Pdb) dictionary

           old_msg    new_msg
0              a/c    account 
1             extend  extend
2             bal     balance
```

I want first dataframe to become like below (replace words with 2nd dataframe)

```
(Pdb) df
          msg
0              the
1               wi
2               fi
3              **account**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `Series` or by `dict`:

```
df['msg'] = df['msg'].replace(dictionary.set_index('old_msg')['new_msg'])
print (df)
       msg
0      the
1       wi
2       fi
3  account
```

Or:

```
df['msg'] = df['msg'].replace(dictionary.set_index('old_msg')['new_msg'].to_dict())
print (df)
       msg
0      the
1       wi
2       fi
3  account
```

Comment: you are savior :)